# How can I access an array item in elasticsearch script

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this mapping for my index:

```
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "medias": {
                    "properties": {
                        "media_id": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "media_type": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "variant": {
                            "properties": {
                                "height": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "url": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "width": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "view_count": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
              
}
```

And I want to write a script for custom scoring like this:

```
    // "_source": "content",
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": " (doc.medias.size() == 0 || doc.medias.view_count.size() == 0 ? 0 : doc.medias.view_count.value) "
                        }
                    
                    }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "content": something"
                }
            },
            "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
"caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "No field found for [medias] in mapping with types []"
                    }
```

I guess I'm not accessing the `view_count` property correctly. How can I do that? And one more thing: the `medias` field is an array and if the size of the array exceeded 1 I need to get the maximum of the `view_count`s. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! You're almost there, you just need to access the doc values like this and you'll get the desired results :

```
    {
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": " (doc['medias.view_count'].size() == 0 ? 0 : doc['medias.view_count'].value) "
        }
      }
    }
```

Since `doc['medias.view_count']` is actually a Java List, if you need to get the maximum of the view count you can do it like this:

```
    {
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": " (doc['medias.view_count'].size() == 0 ? 0 : doc['medias.view_count'].stream().max(Long::compare).get()) "
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! just one more thing: the `medias` field is an array and if the size of the array exceeded 1 I need to get the maximum of the `view_counts`. How can I do this?

Comment: And something else: When the `medias` has more than one element, your script `view_count` returns which one of them?

Comment: `doc['medias.view_count']` is actually a Java List, so you can get any positional element in that list. For instance, `doc['medias.view_count'][2]` would return the third `view_count`